# "Something increases [number]-fond"

Tags: word-meaning

What does **fivefond** mean in the sentence below?

Production increased dramatically some **fivefond/five-fond** between 1990 and 1995.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is regarding a typo. A dictionary check would confirm that no meaning of "fond" could fit here.

Comment: While a search for "define fivefond" does suggest a correction to fivefold, I'm not so sure a dictionary lookup would be helpful if I wasn't already aware of the correct phrase. On the other hand, I don't think specific typos are something that will be widely helpful, and there is an answer that clears it up so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a typo. The correct phrase is *-fold*.

> Profits have increased tenfold in the last year

It is essentially another way of describing multiplication. Saying

> production has increased five-fold between 1990 and 1995

is the same as saying

> Production has increased to five times the original number between 1990 and 1995.

E.g., if the factory was making 1000 widgets a year in 1990, in 1995 they would be making 5000 widgets.